# Powershell compare dates and enable AD User if disabled and in range

Tags: powershell, csv

I can't seem to figure out why this script won't work. There are no errors, but the $User object isn't getting evaluated to $True. The object is to enable a re-hired user's AD account if another system shows the re-hire date to be less than or equal to 8 days out from today.

```
$CSVLine = "C:\scripts\adp\Test ADP Import spec.csv"
$ErrorLog = "C:\scripts\adp\ADPProcessErrors.csv"
$a = Get-Date


ForEach ($row in (import-csv $CSVLine)) {
$User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter ("(sAMAccountName=" + $Row.sAMAccountName + ")") -Properties *
#Write-Host ("User:" + $user.samaccountname + " enabled =" + $user.enabled + " ")
 If ((($User.Enabled -eq $False)) -and ($Row.'Date of hire/rehire' -gt $a) -and (($Row.'Date of hire/rehire') -le ($a.AddDays(8))) )    {

        (Set-ADUser -Enabled $True -Identity $User)
        ("SID:" + $Row.sAMAccountName + ", User:[" + $User.givenName + " " + $User.sn + "] Re-Hire date is in range. Account enabled.") | Out-File -FilePath $ErrorLog -Append

    }    
    } 
                 Write-Host ("CSV Object: " + $Row.'Date of hire/rehire'.GetType())
                 Write-Host ("CSV Object Value:" + $Row.'Date of hire/rehire' + " " )
                 Write-Host ("User:" + $user.samaccountname + " enabled =" + $user.enabled + " ")
```

Comment: Those dates might need to be casted as `[datetime]`/dates so that the math against `$a` would work. It is most likely treating those as string to just doing alphabetical comparison. Cant tell you exactly what to do without sample dates so we can see the formats.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. The dates in the csv are coming back as string on (say) 2/8/2015. Can you give me an example? Also, not sure why your commend isn't coming up as 1 Answer?  Maybe you didn't mark it as an Answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those dates might need to be casted as [datetime]/dates so that the math against `$a` would work. It is most likely treating those as string to just doing alphabetical comparison.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> "b" -gt "a"
True
```

Can't tell you exactly what to do without sample dates so we can see the formats. From the comment if you dates are formatted like "2/8/2015" then a simple cast would address this.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> [datetime]"2/8/2015"
Sunday, February 08, 2015 12:00:00 AM
```

Update your `if` to the following:

```
If ((($User.Enabled -eq $False)) -and ([datetime]($Row.'Date of hire/rehire') -gt $a) -and ([datetime]($Row.'Date of hire/rehire') -le ($a.AddDays(8))) ){
    #.....Process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to say without a sample of the input file but, if you're getting no error, I'd start by checking if `$Row.sAMAccountName` is evaluating to anything inside the loop. Like you have with your commented-out `Write-Host` line, for the `$user` properties.

Cheers.

Comment: The $Row.sAMAccontName is bringing back appropriate properties when I debug and step through this. I think Matt is on the right track but I need a bit more information. Thanks,